# What's the pythonic way to assign default values to be printed by help()?

Tags: python, docstring

I have written the following script to load and assign the default values for the fields that `help()` searches for:

```
import os

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__ )))

def _get_authors():
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__ ))

    with open('%s\AUTHORS' % path, 'r') as authors:
        return ', '.join([author for author in ''.join(authors.readlines()).splitlines()])

def _get_readme():
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__ ))

    with open('%s\README' % path, 'r') as f:
        return ''.join(f.readlines())

def _get_copyright():
    import datetime

    start = 2011
    end = datetime.date.today().year

    if start == end:
        years = str(start)
    else:
        years = "%d - %d" % (start, end)

    return "Copyright %s, %s" % (years, __maintainer__)

__doc__ = _get_readme()
__author__ = _get_authors()
__maintainer__ = "Omer Katz"
__email__ = "omer.drow@gmail.com"
__copyright__ = _get_copyright()
__license__ = "BSD"
__version__ = "0.1.0"
__status__ = "Pre-Alpha"

def _document_api():
    def _document(obj):
        if not getattr(obj, '__author__', None): setattr(obj, '__author__', __maintainer__)
        if not getattr(obj, '__maintainer__', None): setattr(obj, '__maintainer__', __maintainer__)
        if not getattr(obj, '__email__', None): setattr(obj, '__email__', __email__)
        if not getattr(obj, '__copyright__', None): setattr(obj, '__copyright__', __copyright__)
        if not getattr(obj, '__license__', None): setattr(obj, '__license__', __license__)
        if not getattr(obj, '__version__', None): setattr(obj, '__version__', __copyright__)
        if not getattr(obj, '__status__', None): setattr(obj, '__status__', __license__)

    def _document_functions(module):
        from inspect import isfunction
        functions = [getattr(module, function) for function in dir(module) if isfunction(getattr(module, function)) and function != '_']

        for function in functions:
            _document(function)

    def _document_classes(module):
        from inspect import isclass
        classes = [getattr(module, klass) for klass in dir(module) if isclass(getattr(module, klass)) and klass != '_']

        for klass in classes:
            _document_functions(klass)
            _document(klass)


    from pkgutil import walk_packages
    from django.utils.importlib import import_module

    packages = [package for _, package, __ in walk_packages([os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__ ))])]

    for package in packages:
        module = import_module('hammerhead.%s' % package)

        _document_functions(module)
        _document_classes(module)
        _document(module)

_document_api()
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do it?
Is it even a good idea?
`help()` will now be able to print out the correct metadata even if it is not provided.

Any comments on the code are also appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to set all these attributes for each function, class or module?

Comment: @AlexanderArtemenko: Turns out I only need those for modules. I'd like help() and other documentation tools that use this data to print out the correct metadata if it wasn't already provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pythonic way (imho) would be to add docstrings to functions, methods and classes that need documentation, and create a single header (in your `__init__.py` file for the module) that sets the rest of those values for your module.

`__author__`, `__email__`, etc are only defined and used for modules anyways. (See [pydoc](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pydoc.py#l1031).)

Comment: So I need to copy/paste this code into every __init__.py of that module? Sounds like a violation of DRY. I have a script that helps me automate this process, what's unpythonic about it?

Comment: I would just add it to the main `__init__.py` at the base level of the module, such the if someone did `import drowmodule; print drowmodule.__author__` they'd get back `drow`. I'll try to dig up a good example of this.

Comment: For example, https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/__init__.py is the only file in matplotlib that has a `__version__` defined.